# batch "While" loop doesn't work, but why?

Tags: loops, batch-file, while-loop

```
echo off

set /a a=0
:start
if %a% LEQ 21(
echo test
set /a a=%a%+1
goto start
)
```

I don't get it...
I only get a Syntax-error when the loop starts.

Comment: This is not BASH syntax, it's a mashup of Microsoft CMD syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a space between `21` and `(` which will make it compare the number in the loop to `21(`, also breaking the `if` statement, the latter being why you are getting a syntax error.

Add a space and it works fine.

```
echo off

set /a a=0
:start
if %a% LEQ 21 (
echo test
set /a a=%a%+1
goto start
)
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted isn't a valid `bash script` it's a `batch script` to `echo test` 20 times in a `bash script` using a for loop like this:

```
#/bin/bash

for i in {1..20}; do
    echo test
done
```

Much clearer and readable than `batch scripts`, welcome to `bash`!

Comment: sorry, changed that, my fault. faster typing than thinking often result in stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the error already explained by Bali C, you should note that your code have a potential problem. In this command: `set /a a=%a%+1` the %a% value is expanded *just one time* when the `if` command is executed. In this case your code run by chance because the `goto` command cause the `if` be executed again in each loop, but if your program would be larger and more complex, and this set command would be executed several times *inside parentheses*, the code would fail because %a% will be expanded just one time to the value that `a` variable had *before* enter the parentheses.

The way to solve this problem is easy in this case: just eliminate the percent signs, because `set /a a=a+1` command can directly take the values of the variables. However, there is much more involved here! For further details, type `set /?` and pay attention to "delayed variable expansion" description.